# Java how to convert xls data into txt file

Tags: java, xls, text-files

Hi is it possible to convert a excel file into txt file using java?

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/  Technically yes, but if you can, I would recommend C#.  Its libraries are way better for interfacing with Excel documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your file in CSV format and then using "opencsv" (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) you can do whatever you want. BTW, opencsv is a java library.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) to read xls or xlsx file and save it into csv or text format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are Java excel libraries if you google it, but the easiest thing to do is save the excel file as a csv or tab delimited file from within excel itself.

Comment: What I found is convert from txt to xls or csv